# Is there any equivalent of sp_help in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In SQL server, if i write command like this -

> EXEC SP_HELP EmployeeMaster

it'll return my table fields and all the default constraint defined on it. Now i just wants to know that is there any kind of command in postgres like above ?

Although i know to get just table fields in postgres, you can use below query.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'EmployeeMaster'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that *server-side*. Most of PostgreSQL's descriptive and utility commands are implemented in the `psql` client, meaning they are not available to other client applications.

You will need to query the `information_schema` to collect the information you require yourself if you need to do this in a client app.

If you're using PgAdmin-III, well, `psql` is a useful and powerful tool, well worth learning.

Comment: There's something like what you want for views, btw: `pg_get_viewdef` as shown in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html . Nothing for tables. It's frequently requested, but unfortunately, the brains for that are in `pg_dump` and `psql`, and for a mix of social/political, time, and practical reasons they're not going to move into the back-end server in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks again, Craig for sharing that link. And yes i have also found some of the system catalog name - **pg_constraint**, **pg_class**, **pg_attribute**, etc... which will also useful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **pg_constraint, pg_class, pg_attribute** to get the result. See [here](http://postgresql.org) in detail

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you are looking for `Describe Table` property of the Postgres, please go through it

Comment: Okay, i found one link - [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4352E2E8.7060108@starling.us) which tell to use this command - **\d+ tablename**.  But it doesn't work when you execute it using pgAdmin.